# accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null); what does this function do?

Tags: android, email, accountmanager, google-account

What does this function do?  Is it for sign in or sign up?

The documentation says "Adds an account directly to the AccountManager. Normally used by sign-up wizards associated with authenticators, not directly by applications."

I was searching for "how to add account on android" and found this function. Many used this function , so I also tried but got exception "caller uid 10043 is different than the authenticator's uid".

Then, I read the documentation and now I am confused, even if this is for sign up then it is not working for me.

I just want to programmatically add an account (a Gmail account) on Android device either after sign up or sign in.

Comment: you can't add other account then yours(implemented by you) ... just ask user to do it (or select existing one) using `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent` ... it's not exists on API < 15 but it can be easly implemented using andoird source

Comment: thanks for response! Are you saying that I can add an account which is implemented by me? means? My own account? How will I do this? I don't want any UI, I just want to add a hard coded gmail account.

Comment: here is the sample of own account type: %ANDROID_SDK%\samples\android-10\SampleSyncAdapter